# running a linux script to check on process and if stopped how to make it start the process

Tags: scripting, novell

We are running OES2/SuSE.  The problem is with our groupwise webaccess.  From time to time it stops and we just have to restart the process.  The commands are:

`rcgrpwise status`
`rcgrpwise start`

How would I create a script that would check the status and if it comes back stopped, then it would run the rcgrpwise start command.

Comment: Is it actually stopped, or has it died (was killed)? There's a huge difference in UNIX world between those two states...

Comment: One more thing: checking *why* it crashed will be much more productive. Check logs. It also may be a sign of some other problem (faulty RAM).

Answer (score 2):

If it's a really simple process to start I would probably add it to inittab with a respawn entry. Otherwise look at using something like [monit to check and automatically restart processes](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-monitor-and-restart-linux-unix-service.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
typeset -i RC
rcgrpwise status >dev/null 2>&1
let RC=$?
if [ $RC -ne 0 ]
   then
     rcpgrwise restart
fi
sleep 3
rcgrpwise status >/dev/null 2>&1
exit $?
```

Save this as script and call it from cron.

or shorter:

`rcgrpwise status >/dev/null 2>&1 || rcgrpwise restart`

But as others have stated - you should research why this is stalling.